# High memory consumption for script with imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php

I have built the following code to check and convert a JPG to a WebP image.

This seems to be using a lot of memory, currently approx 14680064 when the WebP file already exists, and 27262976 when a WebP is created.

Can anyone tell me if this is 'normal' and if there are any amendments I could make to optimize this code?

```
$path = 'http://www.domain.co.uk/images/uploads/gallery/1.jpg';

if ( !empty($path) ) 
{       
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp' ) !== false ) 
    {               
        $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        $domain_path = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

        $filename = basename($path);
        $filename_no_ext = basename($path, ".jpg");

        $path = str_replace($domain_path, ".", $path);
        $path_without_filename = str_replace($filename, "", $path);

        $save_to_path = $path_without_filename.$filename_no_ext.'.webp';

        if ( file_exists($path) )
        {
            if ( ! file_exists($save_to_path) )
            {           
                $temp = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);

                imagewebp($temp, $save_to_path);                        
                imagedestroy($temp);
            }
        }

        return substr($save_to_path, 1);
    } 
    else
    {
        return $path;
    }
}
```

Comment: How large is the uploaded image? As a rule of thumb, it'll use approximately pixel width \* height \* 3 bytes of memory. Your observed memory consumption corresponds to roughly a 3000x3000px image.

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert ?

Comment: Thanks @deceze, that is really helpful. I didn't know that was the calculation. You are correct that these images are 3000px longest egde.

Comment: Loading the image into memory (e.g. `imagecreatefromjpeg`) stores the raw image data in memory, which is a byte per color (RGB) per pixel…